# How to limit access on an access point?

Tags: tomato

I have a Linksys router running Tomato Shibby. Connected to that main router is a wireless access point. I would like devices connected to the wireless AP to be limited by bandwidth. Can someone teach me how please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice solution for this. Steps:

1. Within Basic->Network, under LAN, create a new Bridge, which in my case is br1. 
   [image: new bridge setup]
2. Within Advanced->VLAN, create a new VLAN, which in my case is "3", and assign the port to which the access point you want to limit is connected. In my case this is port #3.

[image: New VLAN]

3. Within Bandwidth Limiter, check the Enable Limiter box, and under "Default Class for LAN1 (br1)" set the limits that you want.

[image: bandwidth limiter]

That's it! Rinse and repeat as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the Bandwith Limiter (B/W Limiter page in the left menus, under QoS) part of the QoS settings. It should look very similar to this older 1.21 version image:

[image]

I couldn't answer perfectly for your specific situation, but the devil is in the details with QoS settings. One fellow in 2013 said that QoS and Bandwith Limiting were best used separately, having both at the same time was bad (at the time anyway). Here's some info on what to change and maybe even why:

- **[IP/MAC Bandwidth limiter for Tomato mod release. User Manual.](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/ip-mac-bandwidth-limiter-for-tomato-mod-release-user-manual.26670/)** - Edited & posts by Toastman (a maintainer/creator of the Toastman builds)
- [Shibby's Tomato: need help with bandwidth limiting](http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/shibbys-tomato-need-help-with-bandwidth-limiting.68494/) (image above is from here)
- [Ensure a Fast Internet Connection When You Need It](http://lifehacker.com/326543/ensure-a-fast-internet-connection-when-you-need-it) - Pretty lifehacker guide with images, about dd-wrt but the same principles apply
- [Using Tomato's QOS System - tomatousb.org](http://tomatousb.org/tut:using-tomato-s-qos-system)
- [Tomato QoS Config Guide, with functioning downstream QoS](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/tomatoqos/2._The_Guide)
- [DuckDuckGo web search for "tomato qos guide"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tomato%20qos%20guide)

Comment: No problem :-) QoS seems like a hard to perfect feature, but hopefully the info will be good enough. Maybe it's even the best / check-mark answer... *hint*