# What adapter should I use for my old desktop HD?

Tags: adapter, hard-drive

My brother removed the HD of my old computer and gave it to me. He said that with an adaptor I could connect it to my laptop. I bought one, but it wasn’t exactly the right one. Can anyone help me finding the right adaptor for my HD? I’d like to recover my files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A 64 GB sdcard or USB stick could be cheaper than an adaptor for this ancient HDD.

Comment: Question was edited after my comment...

Comment: @JakeGould it's true I edited the question after Turbo J asked why. I wanted to clarify the main question to other users. This is the one I got http://www.ebuyer.com/341689-startech-usb-2-0-to-sata-ide-adapter-usb2sataide I thought it should work, but I get an alert saying "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer"

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest using an old computer with the appropriate old IDE/PATA connectors. They're likely to be found free or for pocket change on sites like [craigslist](http://craigslist.org) or [kijiji in canada](http://kijiji.ca) (kijiji had it's name changed to [eBay Classifieds](http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/) in the usa?) or at a garage sale, or borrow one from a friend with a closet full of old computer stuff. Many old ones I've seen were retired because their old hard drive failed, and some of them had IDE/PATA *and* SATA connectors, if you want to copy directly to a newer hard drive.

I would be reluctant to try booting up the old Windows on the old drive, just in case the drive could be close to failing and you want to recover your data first. Booting a live Linux USB/DVD (like [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/) or [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/)) you could even mount the old hard drive (as read-only (ro) if you don't want to risk deleting anything important) and browse & copy your files, or do a backup image of the whole drive (if it's failing then linux & `gddrescue` could be great, see [Ubuntu Help - Data Recovery - Imaging a damaged device, filesystem or drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Imaging_a_damaged_device.2C_filesystem_or_drive)). It's small enough to fit on a USB stick, or you could network with your regular laptop and share files with your laptop over the network .

---

Or you could use an IDE USB Adapter like [this Vantec SATA/IDE to USB 3.0 Adapter](http://www.legitreviews.com/vantec-sata-ide-to-usb-3-adapter-review_131412)
[image: Vantec SATA/IDE to USB 3.0 Adapter image from legitreviews.com]
the extras like a power supply as Ecnerwal mentioned *should* be included with most of them.
You should be extra careful with a hard drive sitting on a table and working, desktop hard drives were traditionally less forgiving of being bumped around than laptop drives, especially an old one.

---

Or you could use an IDE to USB hard drive enclosure, which is basically the same as above, but with a box around it like this image (has the lid of the "box" removed):
[image: hard disk enclosure image from Wikipedia]

Whatever you do, I'd handle the old drive very gently whether it's on or off, especially if you still have important data you want to recover. Bumping or banging it around now is likely to be bad for it.

Image sources: [www.legitreviews.com](http://www.legitreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ide-testing-645x409.jpg) and [wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Usb_firewire_hard_disk_enclosure.jpg).

Comment: These two options (external adapter or enclosure) are the best options. +1

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the image sourcing. They were direct image links when I entered them, if they had stayed directly linked to the sources then would a note saying where they're from still be desired? Maybe as the image description would be ok?

Comment: (1) FWIW, [Boann](http://superuser.com/users/287975/boann) [imported the images](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/460148) without preserving any trace of the source (except for the textual link to www.legitreviews.com/vantec-sata-ide-to-usb-3-adapter-review_131412); I was just reacting to that.  We like to import images to i.stack.imgur.com because we have a special relationship with them, and we want Super User to continue to work even if every other web site goes down (i.e., we don’t like direct image links to sources).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) states the Stack Exchange policy.  The rules for referencing images are unclear, and I suspect that there are plenty of posts that do it the same way your answer did.  But the policy says “Provide a link to the original page or answer.”  I interpret that to mean that the citation / reference should be visible text, and what I inserted might still fall short of what the rules require.

Comment: …  But [I see now](http://superuser.com/questions/997269/how-to-limit-access-on-an-access-point/997274#comment1378112_997274) that you're already familiar with that.  :-)  ⁠

Comment: Wasn't sure about the image sourcing either, (added to my other post too) the "image text/name" for the image seems good enough, though it doesn't seem to appear as a popup in my firefox or chromium, maybe I'm just buggy ;-) Good idea to have an image copy in case the original goes down, I'm tempted to leave wikipedia's link as-is, but it probably gets edited and moved/removed every so often too

Comment: @Xen2050 Do you think I should've been able to recover my files using this? http://www.ebuyer.com/341689-startech-usb-2-0-to-sata-ide-adapter-usb2sataide Because that's what I tried using but I get an alert saying "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer".

Comment: It looks like it *should* work, but that doesn't mean it necessarily will work. I tried a few similar items, one would work for a few minutes then quit, one enclosure type was great, and another enclosure didn't work at all with a hard drive, but did work with a dvd drive. Could be that the hard drive itself isn't working perfectly either, I'm unfamiliar with that error but if it asks you to format the drive I'd say **NO** until you can at least make a backup copy & get your data.

Answer (score 5):

Standard [PATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) (Parallel Advanced Technology Attachment) drive - rather old-school these days, but common as heck previously. You might need an external power supply to connect it to most laptops (I presume you are adapting to USB for the laptop connection - these drives expect 5 and 12 volts and even if your adapter had a dc/dc converter to make 12V, the wattage is more than most USB ports are happy supplying.)

Then follows the question of why? 40 GB can be had now in many more convenient and compact forms, (possibly for less money than the adaptor) so unless you have files you did not transfer and need to get off it, the practical value of it as an external drive is negligible.

Comment: @Exnerwal that's the HD of the computer I had more than 10 years ago and I'd like to check this pandora box ;)

Comment: The USB adapters usually also include a power supply.

Answer (score 2):

The gadget you need is called a PATA USB 3.5'' enclosure. Quick googling gave me [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VNJD1S) and it looks just fine for me. I have got more than a decade of experience wth these things, still using one (although of a different brand) actively with a bucket of hard drives of exactly same model happily. I can help finding it in a catalogue of a local hardware store near you if share a link to one.

Comment: That enclosure is probably worth more than the drive.  :-)

Comment: Indeed, @fixer1234, as these old drives are worth not more than a dollar or two nowadays (I would be glad to donate a dozen of them if somebody near me was interested, I just don't feel good about throwing perfectly functional hardware I don't need any more away to the garbage can, it feels like throwing out a pet for me), but I have just bought one a decade ago and have used it with more than a hundred of hard drives since then. A CD/DVD/BlueRay recorder drive costs more than empty CD/DVD/BlueRay disks too :-)